# ¿Cual es la url de despliegue de una app Web Logic Server 11g?

Tags: java, weblogic

Si mal no recuerdo en el pasado pude acceder asi:

localhost:7001/producer/NOMBRE_DE_MI_APP

pero ahora no puedo levantar ninguna app que despliego en el servidor.

La aplicacion se despliega sin errores pero por mas que intento URLs no logro acceder a la app.

Comment: En teoría lo de "producer" te sobra, normalmente es `localhost:<puerto>/<nombre_aplicacion>`

Comment: Pablo si colocas solo un comentario no puedo colocar la respuesta como correcta, por favor colocalo como respuesta a la pregunta para darte la confirmacion. Gracias por tu ayuda, me funciono, aparentemente estaba colocando mal alguna letra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, en cualquier contenedor J2EE (Tomcat, JBoss, WebLogic, Websphere) corriendo en local, la URL de la aplicación es:

```
localhost:<puerto>/<nombre_aplicacion>
```

El puerto puede variar, Tomcat usa por defecto el 8080 pero es algo configurable en el fichero `server.xml`